# What are the floating orbs in a circle that float behind powerful characters?

Tags: tropes

I know there's normally a specific answer for each show they're in and explanations but what do they originate from culturally? I've seen them quite a few times and I don't think it's just a design coincidence

Comment: Could you give a few examples of this happening? I can't think of any instances of this off the top of my head (the closest that comes to mind are Bleach's Toshiro Hitsuga's ice flowers or maybe Gundam Seed's Prominence Gundam's DRAGOON weapon pods neither of which are orbs)

Comment: Can you provide an image of the trope?

Comment: You mean aureola? https://butsuzo-nyumon.com/aureola Similar things are seen in West, too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halo_(religious_iconography)